# Non-English numbers for citations

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, citations, bibliography

In Microsoft Word 2010, when I use the `insert citation` from the `Citation & Bibliography` pane, it always inserts **English numbers**. For a non-English text, this is not really good.

I have set the `Numeral` to `context` and if I enter a number in the text, I see non-English numbers. However in the case of citations, I always see English numbers. Is there anyway to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are specified the language of each source correctly:

From `Citation & Bibliography` pane select `Manage Sources`

In `Source Manager` window from `Master List` choose desired source, and click `Edit...`

In `Edit Source` window from `Language` drop-down menu located at top-right corner, choose native language for selected source.(e.g. for my Persian sources I choose Persian from drop-down menu, otherwise digits in Persian text will be displayed in English) then click `OK`.

Note that if this source is available on current document (so you could see it in `Current List` on the right side of `Master List`), Word will alert you to apply changes on that too, so we click `Yes`.

`Close` the `Source Manager` and `Update` your field.

This should do the job, but you may also need to correct text direction.

Comment: It didn't work for me. Can you show us a picture where you see non-english numbers in [].

Comment: You're right. I hadn't worked with IEEE style. Using this style, When I use Insert Citation, the numbers in brackets are still English, but For bibliographies there isn't such problem. If I find any solution I will share with you.